# MySQL から PostgreSQLへの変換

Tags: mysql, postgresql

PostersSQLを勉強しています。MySQLでは下記のようにすると外部キー制約等リレーションがうまくいくのですが、PostersSQLの場合、少し構文が変わると思い変えてみてはいますがうまくいきません。

MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `username` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `authorities` (
  `username` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `authority` varchar(80) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`username`);

ALTER TABLE `authorities`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`,`authority`);

ALTER TABLE `authorities`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `authorities_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`);
```

PostgreSQL

```
                                                                                               
CREATE TABLE users (  
　username varchar(80) NOT NULL,  
　password varchar(80) NOT NULL,
　　　　　　　↓tinyintはないのでsmallintに変更  
　enabled smallint(1) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE authorities (  
　username varchar(80) NOT NULL,  
　authority varchar(80) NOT NULL);

                                                                             
ALTER TABLE users  
　ADD PRIMARY KEY (username);

ALTER TABLE authorities  
　　　　↓UNIQUE KEY（PostgreSQLの場合はUNIQUE?
　ADD UNIQUE username (username,authority);

ALTER TABLE authorities  
　ADD CONSTRAINT authorities_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username);
```

上記のやり方によるエラー

```
ERROR:  "("またはその近辺で構文エラー
行 1: ...  password varchar(80) NOT NULL,  enabled smallint(1) NOT NU...
                                                           ^
ERROR:  リレーション"authorities"はすでに存在します
ERROR:  リレーション"users"は存在しません
ERROR:  "username"またはその近辺で構文エラー
行 1: ALTER TABLE authorities  ADD UNIQUE username (username,autho...
                                          ^
ERROR:  リレーション"users"は存在しません
```

・smallint(1)でエラーになっているので、smallintのみにする。
・ALTER TABLE authorities  ADD UNIQUE username (username,autho...部分の修正方法がわかりません。
・その他修正が必要か？

ご教授いただけたら幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> smallint(1)でエラーになっているので、smallintのみにする。

はい。
もしくは桁数をユーザ指定精度にするならば`numeric`型をご検討ください。
[数値データ型](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/8.2/html/datatype-numeric.html)

ちなみに`enabled numeric(1, 0) NOT NULL`のように1桁精度を指定した場合、小数点以下は丸められます。

```
insert into users values('piyo', 'foo', 0.1); -- enabledが0に丸められる
insert into users values('bar', 'buz', 10);    -- エラー
```

> ALTER TABLE authorities ADD UNIQUE username

[CREATE INDEX](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.3/html/sql-createindex.html)に書き換え可能です。

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX username ON authorities (username,authority);
```

[ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.4/html/sql-altertable.html)でユニークキーを追加したことがないので自信はないのですが、リンク先の ADD `table_constraint_using_index` の通り既存のインデックスを使用する構文ではないでしょうか。(下記の太字は筆者)

> この構文は、**既存の一意性インデックス**に基づき、テーブルにPRIMARY KEYまたはUNIQUE制約を新たに追加します。

> その他修正が必要か？

SQL文に全角スペースが含まれているので半角スペースに変更した方が良いのではないでしょうか。

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/27d7a/1)でビルド可能なSQL：

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  username varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(80) NOT NULL,
-- enabled smallint NOT NULL
  enabled numeric(1, 0) NOT NULL);
  
CREATE TABLE authorities (
  username varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  authority varchar(80) NOT NULL);
  
ALTER TABLE users  
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (username);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX username
  ON authorities (username,authority);

ALTER TABLE authorities  
  ADD CONSTRAINT authorities_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username);

insert into users values('hoge', 'fuga', 9);  -- 正常
insert into users values('piyo', 'foo', 0.1); -- enabledが0に丸められる
-- insert into users values('bar', 'buz', 10);    -- エラー
```

Comment: 無事テーブル作成ができました。numeric、CREATE UNIQUE INDEX の使い方を知り勉強になりました。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL には boolean 型がありますが、MySQL には無いので 代わりに tinyint(1) が使われることがよくあります。

この enabled が true, false を保持するためのカラムなのであれば、boolean を使うのがいいと思います。

Comment: ご回答いただいた通り作成後、booleanの型の問題でエラーになりました。型を変更しようとしましたができなかったので、こちらの記事　https://qiita.com/seiketkm/items/9d069348c2906a6ae011　を参考にしてキャストすることができましたが、初めのテーブルをcreateする段階でboolean型を指定しておけばよかったですかね。

Comment: MySQL だと ALTER TABLE で型を変更できるのですが、自分は PostgreSQL はあんまり詳しくないのでできるかどうかわかりません…。